# Developer Tools - Internet Explorer vs. Chrome - Scraping

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am a little new to scraping so pardon if I am not detailed in my question. I have an internal website in my company and I am trying to scrape data from it. The issue that the website is only compatible with IE Explorer and when opening in Chrome, the vast majority of the data is missing and it is not structured correctly. When opening the developer tools in Explorer, the area that I am trying to get data from is like a black box (see below - that is what I get when I select element). On the other hand, when I open it in Chrome, the area that was a black box in Chrome is no longer a black box and I can scrape the data. The issue is that site is not compatible with Chrome and most of the relevant data is not showing up.

```html
<FRAME name=HauptFenster src="blank.html" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto"></frame>
```

I am trying to figure how to scrape it within Explorer if possible. Why would Explorer developer tools show less items than Chrome? Any help or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this belongs on stackoverflow.  this site is for specific programming questions.  I don't know what you think you are going to scrape from developer tools that you cannot get from page source.  Any data that is coming from a database won't be available to you in any browser, only the rendered html.

Comment: Well my intent is to write a macro to extract the data. Not sure what would be the best resource for asking this question though.

Comment: There are scraping tools already out there.  You could use wget (GnuWin32) which is a command line tool so browser has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If possible then try to post the screenshot of the web page that contains the iframe and let us know what data you want to scrape from it. If it is possible then try to create a sample demo. Try to provide it here. So that we can try to check it and try to make a tests with it. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. We can try to provide suggestions based on that sample. Please note that you do not need to share any confidential or personal data. You can replace it with the dummy values. Thanks for your understanding.